# ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer responsivo el fontSize de un Text?

Tags: flutter, dart

Actualmente estoy haciendo las vistas de una aplicación para tablet pero tengo algunos problemas con el Texto ya que todo se ajusta a las distintas medidas de pantalla menos mi "texto" y no he encontrado alguna forma de solucionar mi problema.

```
Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.8,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.35,
                          color: Color(0xFFF1F1F1),
                          padding:  EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child:
                          ListView(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("""12345""", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xFF1D539B),
                              ),
                              ),
                              Text("""Juan Perez Perez""", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xFF141414)
                              ),
                              ),
                              Text("""Operador de Valores""", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xFF141414)
                              ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Actualmente ocupo MediaQuery para ajustar mis contenedores a la pantalla.

Distintos tamaños:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar también `MediaQuery` para el texto, pero tendrías que definir un tamaño de referencia , yo usaría `700` , que es el alto de un móvil estándar.

```
  final sizeReference = 700.0;

  double getResponsiveText(double size) =>
      size * sizeReference / MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide;
```

Y para usarlo, lo haces así :

```
Text("Hello World", style: TextStyle(fontSize: getResponsiveText(18) )
```